# How to join maps from List of Maps in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this List:

```
var listMap = [
        {
          "type": "Spouse",
          "name": "Mother",
          "age": 50
        },
        {
          "type": "Family",
          "name": "Lili",
          "age": 16
        },

];
```

> var finalResult = [
> "type": "Spouse",
> "name": "Mother",
> "age": 50,
> "type": "Family",
> "name": "Lili",
> "age": 16, ];

How can i achieve finalResult?

Comment: You can't have a list like that, with key/value I mean.

Comment: Can you let us know your use case? Maybe that way we can help you.

Comment: You can have two lists of String. One for the keys and another for the values. You can use the same index into the two lists to find the kay and value. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 List<Map<String,dynamic>> listMap = [
        {
          "type": "Spouse",
          "name": "Mother",
          "age": 50
        },
        {
          "type": "Family",
          "name": "Lili",
          "age": 16
        },

];
```

try to loop them and add them 1 by 1

```
    for(var x in listMap){
          for(var y in x.entries){
            newList.add("${jsonEncode(y.key)}:${jsonEncode(y.value)}");
          }
       }
      // or use print
    log(newList.toList().toString());
```

result

```
["type":"Spouse", "name":"Mother", "age":50, "type":"Family", "name":"Lili", "age":16]
```

you can try this to dart pad.